# Is this a typical supervising style and what should I do to make research progress?

Tags: research-process, advisor, supervision

I am a research master student in STEM field. My supervisor and I have weekly meetings. Each meeting lasts for about 15-20 minutes. Before each meeting, I will summarize the most important work I have done in a week in a powerpoint and will present my work to him in each weekly meeting. Then my supervisor will ask me some questions based on my work and I will explain some particular details to him. If there is anything I cannot answer him, I will look into that particular details after the meeting, revise my design and reply to him in the next meeting. This supervising style sounds good because both my supervisor and I are both responsive to our duties.

However, whenever I have technical difficulties (too often actually), I cannot get help from my supervisor or my labmates. For example, when I did some theoretical proof work and sent my work to him, he did not read it and give me comments (though I understand that it takes extra time or non-meeting time for him to read my work and he is busy with other duties). Also when the system I have been designing generates simulation errors, he would not look into the simulation details with me. Instead he would just say something like "there must be some problems, you need to solve it". Or he would just ask me to break the whole system into smaller modules and look into each of the modules. But I have already been doing this. It seems that every time I need to solve the problem by myself. I try to ask my labmates for help. But their research topics are somewhat different from mine. So they cannot offer me much help. Though I am happy to look into the technical difficulties by myself and regard it as an opportunity to learn (and get some self-satisfaction when I get the problems solved), it takes me so much time which makes me look like an inefficient researcher.

Now my research has been progressing very slowly. And I am very worried that I cannot graduate on time. Also I still want to achieve a good result in my research and hope I can publish a paper. Is there anything I can do to accelerate my research progress? Is there any technique to solve the technical problems in a more timely manner?

Also, is the supervising style a typical one? Is it reasonable to expect my supervisor to look into the details of my work with me? Or professors would usually regard technical details are too trivial and expect their research students to have adequate experience and knowledge to solve these problems?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Questions about how to do your research are generally closed on this site.  Questions about supervision style are okay.  Please ask one question per post.

Comment: You cannot expect your supervisor to help you debug your code!  I tell my students exactly the same thing as your supervisor.   I do, however, test my students to ensure that they understand the theory or what they are trying to implement.  I leave them to the details.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it reasonable to expect my supervisor to look into the details of my work with me?

No.  Some supervisors might do that, others might not.  It is reasonable for you to expect your supervisor to identify resources that will help you work independently.

> is the supervising style a typical one?

There is no typical supervising style.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what the answer to this question will give you.

Suppose that you are told that all advisors are like this; how will this help you any more than hearing that your advisor’s style is way off?

It sounds like a fairly typical interaction a professor might have with a masters student. Weekly meetings are good, checking in to see that you’re trying stuff is good, but perhaps not reading your results quickly is less than optimal.

Perhaps a more apt question to ask is: is this supervision style good for *you*?

From the way you describe it, it sounds like the answer is no.

I suggest you try to ask your advisor for more detailed/personal attention (unlikely to happen), direct you to resources that will help you move forward (like a fellow grad student/postdoc, or a class you can take), or be more self directed.

Comment: One reason why the question makes sense: If it turned out that OP's advisor is particular poor, that would make it more likely that switching an advisor might lead to an improvement.

Comment: At least in my university, changing MSc advisors can take a while, and is not necessarily worth the time it would take.